# Maven & JavaFX: Missing JavaFX application class

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I try to build my JavaFX application with maven. But currently the following error appears:

```
Missing JavaFX application class com.company.app.Main
```

The following codepart defines this:

```
<manifestEntries>
    <JavaFX-Version>{javafx.version}+</JavaFX-Version>
    <Main-Class>com.company.app.Main</Main-Class>
    <implementation-version>2.0</implementation-version>
    <JavaFX-Application-Class>com.company.app.Main</JavaFX-Application-Class>
    <JavaFX-Class-Path>

    </JavaFX-Class-Path>
    <Class-Path>javafx-${javafx.version}.jar</Class-Path>
</manifestEntries>
```

The Main.java File contains the following code:

```
public class Main extends Application
```

So for me, everything looks fine... Does somebody know, why maven doens't find the class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. There was no sourcecode compiled, because I do not follow the standard directory layout: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html